# Awk BEGIN example

Tags: regex, awk

```
$ cat tables.txt | awk 'BEGIN {
RS="\nStation"
FS="\n"
}
{ print $1 }
'
```

Running the above command in the above format or as a script gives me the desired output.

```
08594: SAL                     , CAPE VERDE
```

But if I try running the same in CLI as a single gives me error as syntax. What I am doing wrong here?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS="\nStation" FS="\n" }{ print $1 }' tables.txt
```

Comment: Try: `awk 'BEGIN { RS="\nStation"; FS="\n" }{ print $1 }' tables.txt`

Comment: that helped , just got it

Comment: ok will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\nStation"; FS="\n" }{ print $1 }' tables.txt
```

i.e. use `;` to terminate one assignment before starting another i.e. `FS="\n"`.